# Maintain form data when reloading web page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Basically, I have a web page that automatically reloads every 5 seconds using the JavaScript code below

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

This works fine, my page is reloading. However, my page also contains a form entry that allows you to type a comment. It is like so...

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="title">
```

Very simple. However, what I want to do is to have that form keep its contents when the page automatically reloads. I want to be able to type something into the comment box and when the page reloads, have what I just typed remain in the comment box.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can store the content in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the content in the cookie and whenever you need this content you can fetch this content from the cookie.

find below code

```
function setCookie(){
var cookieString = "data";
document.cookie = cookieString;
}

function getCookie(){
alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register an event like `onkeyup` on the `input` and in that event store the content in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). When page loads you check `localStorage` for data.

```
text.onkeyup = function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem("title", text.value);
}

function init() {
    if (localStorage.title)
        text.value = localStorage.title;
}
```

You call this function when body loads like

```
<body onload="init()">
...
```

You can learn more about `localStorage` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).